# D3 with React Hooks - how to update bars without redraw the entire chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, charts, react-hooks

I am new with D3 and I am trying to create a BarChart component.
In the code below the *exit()* & *remove()* functions are not working and every time it draws new chart instead of updating the bars with the new values.

I tried to use this line ***selectAll('svg > g').remove()**;* but it redraw the entire chart every
time the data updates.

Also I tried to create the SVG outside ***useEffect*** but it dose not work.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import {
    select,
    selectAll,
    max,
    scaleLinear,
    scaleBand
} from 'd3';
import { BarChartContainer } from './BarChart.style';

const DEFAULT_MARGIN = { top: 25, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 55 };
const BAR_PADDING_RATIO = 0.25;
const ALL_BARS_CLASS = 'bars';

const BarChart = ({ dataset, onBarClick, size }) => {
    const svgRef = useRef(null);

    const margin = DEFAULT_MARGIN;

    const width = size.width - margin.left - margin.right;
    const height = size.height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    const getXScale = () =>
        scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, max(dataset, d => d.value)])
            .range([0, width]);

    const getYScale = () =>
        scaleBand()
            .domain(dataset.map(d => d.label))
            .range([0, height])
            .padding(BAR_PADDING_RATIO);

    const drawBars = (svg, xScale, yScale) => {
        // HORIZONTAL BARS
        const bars = svg.append('g').attr('class', ALL_BARS_CLASS);
        const rects = bars.selectAll('rect').data(dataset);

        rects
            .exit()
            .transition()
            .duration(700)
            .attr('width', 0)
            .attr('x', 0)
            .remove();

        // UPDATE
        rects
            .transition()
            .duration(700)
            .attr('x', 0)
            .attr('y', d => yScale(d.label))
            .attr('width', d => xScale(d.value))
            .attr('height', yScale.bandwidth())
            .attr('fill', 'blue');

        rects
            .enter()
            .append('rect')
            .attr('class','bar')
            .attr('x', 1)
            .attr('y', d => yScale(d.label))
            .attr('height', yScale.bandwidth())
            .transition()
            .duration(700)
            .attr('width', d => xScale(d.value))
            .attr('fill', 'green')
    };

    useEffect(
        () => {
            // remove all nested groups and redraw the chart when data changes
            // selectAll('svg > g').remove();

            // include the SVG and nested g element in which to plot the visualization
            const svg = select(svgRef.current)
                .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${size.width + margin.left} ${size.height + margin.top}`)
                .append('g')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(85, 15)');

            // SCALES
            const xScale = getXScale();
            const yScale = getYScale();
            // BARS
            drawBars(svg, xScale, yScale);
        },
        [JSON.stringify(dataset)]
    );

    return (
        <BarChartContainer>
            <svg ref={svgRef} />
        </BarChartContainer>
    );
};

export default BarChart;
```

Comment: If you add a `g` every time you update (`const bars = svg.append('g')`), then `rects` will always be an empty selection because `bars.selectAll('rect')` won't select anything: there are no `rect`s in the new `g`, so you will not exit anything. Add the `g` once prior to drawing the bars, then in the drawBars function re-use that same `g` with the enter/update/exit selection.

Comment: yes, you are right. But I don't know where I should append (g). When I defined bars outsite the drawBars function it does not work

Comment: I'll take a look tonight - a few solutions come to mind and I want to present a more idiomatic solution for react than something that might work but is an atypical pattern.

Comment: Haven't had much of a chance to look further and am getting ready for a canoe trip. Is it not possible to add the g either as part of the component the same way you add the SVG or add it on initializing it?

Comment: I tried to define bars under svg but it also redraws the chart when data updates not updating the bars itself. Thanks for help Andrew, have a nice trip :))